# BurpSuite - Setting proxy for local network

Tags: burp

For testing few things I want multiple devices to connect on burp suite proxy at once. For example my PC + my notebook + my phone. I try to proxy listen whole network on some specific port but without success.

Is there a way how to setup BURP SUITE proxy for more devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to configure BurpSuite to listen on a non-loopback interface.

Click on the 'Proxy Tab' -> 'Options' -> 'Add'

Then specify the port and the address to listen on.  Or set it to listen on all interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you go the "Proxy/Options/Proxy Listeners" and edit the listener, you can set it to "All interfaces" or to a "Specific Interface":

[Burp screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNuaI.png)

This means that on the networks where the selected interfaces are available you can configure your devices to used that interface. If you want to use other interfaces, but not all, you can still create more proxy listeners, each listening on a different interface.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this by using [NTLMaps](https://github.com/heupel/ntlmaps) and sharing Wifi from my computer to the devices.

In NTLMaps folder locater server.cfg and open it in a text editor
Change the following lines of the config file:

- PARENT_PROXY:[Proxy Address] 
  (e.g. PARENT_PROXY:127.0.0.1 for burpsuite)
- PARENT_PROXY_PORT:[####]
  (e.g. PARENT_PROXY_PORT:8080 for burpsuite)
- ALLOW_EXTERNAL_CLIENTS:1
- NT_DOMAIN:Computer-Name-iMac.local (This is name of local network on Mac, found at Settings > Sharing > Hit Edit on Computer Name, Not sure where it is on PC settings but shouldn't be hard to find.)

Connect Device to Shared Proxy.
Edit the connection settings on that device to use a proxy for your shared internet.

iOS

- Settings > Wifi > Your Shared Networ > Info Button HTTP Proxy > Manual
- Set Server to the
  value found for Router in the Table above this in the menu 
  (Settings > WiFi > IP Address Section > DHCP Tab > Server)
- Set Port to LISTEN_PORT found in NTMLMaps server.cfg file (Should be defaulted to
  5865)
- Install certificate of proxy you're using on device (for [burp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225459/burp-suite-page-keeps-on-loading-after-proxy-is-configured-on-firefox-to-record/37351828#37351828))

On Android

1. Obtain the Networks DCHP Server address with a program like Wifi Inspector or use iOS device connected to same network to get server address
2. Go to Settings > WiFi
   Hold down the name of the Network you're connected and select Modify Network
3. Advanced Options
4. Proxy set to Manual
5. Proxy Hostname to IP address from step 1
6. Port to LISTEN_PORT found in NTMLMaps server.cfg file (Should be defaulted to 5865)
7. IP Settings DHCP should be fine.
8. Save
9. Install certificate of proxy you're using on device (Note will require a passcode being used on lock screen) (for [burp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225459/burp-suite-page-keeps-on-loading-after-proxy-is-configured-on-firefox-to-record/37351828#37351828))

Open terminal
Run the main.py file for NTLMaps (I set a bash profile alias so I can run it on quick from terminal), then use the internet on device once it's been set up to use the proxy. Note, on Android if the connection is not setup to use the proxy before booting the app it won't use it until you quit and reboot.