# Burp Unable To access proxy Server Error in Android

Tags: android, proxy, burp

Hello guys I installed premium edition of burp  few months ago.I can easily intercept the applicaton in web from my pc.But the problem arises when I tried to intercept apps from my Android device. I tried very hard and searchedc any possible solution in the web but nothing worked for me.I keep getting unable to access through proxy server error when I connect burp with my mobile and try to visit a Http site.Also can you tell me how to intercept request from apps like messenger , Facebook For Android etc ...

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by, "when I connect burp with my mobile"

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically have 2 problems I just answered. 
You may be getting an error on your mobile because you have not added the certificate to the device. Easy way to install [cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225459/burp-suite-page-keeps-on-loading-after-proxy-is-configured-on-firefox-to-record/37351828#37351828).
I use a program called NTLMaps to proxy a shared internet connection to Burp which routes the App Traffic through Burpsuite. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453212/burpsuite-setting-proxy-for-local-network/37400605#37400605).