# Burp Suite: Page keeps on loading after proxy is configured on Firefox to record activities

Tags: url, proxy, load, fiddler, burp

When I set proxy to record activities in Burp Suite, URL keeps on loading, though manually without proxy it works. Its only while recording with Proxy, URL keeps on loading.

Any idea why URL does not work while recording with Proxy?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a certificate for Burp proxy to your browser. The easiest way to get the certificate is to point your browser at the proxy and go to http://burp the hit the 'CA Certificate' button in the top right side of the window. Once downloaded follow these instructions https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783075-installing-burp-s-ca-certificate-in-your-browser.